# finding the data from database whose field is in datetime datatype

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have used the following code to get the data of the field having it's datatype datetime but it executed the result as empty set. Please help me to solve it.

```
mysql_query("set @last_day=last_day(now()-interval 1 month),@first_day=(@last_day-interval 1 month)+interval 1 day");
$result=mysql_query("select * from `gcm_users` where (`created_at` between @first_day and @last_day)") or die("could not fire the query");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo $row['created_at'];
    exit;
}
```

the created_at field has datetime datatype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do two queries like that, one to set variables and another to use them.  This isn't a stored procedure.

Do it by using PHP variables and concatenating:

```
$last_day = "last_day(now()-interval 1 month)";
$first_day = "({$last_day}-interval 1 month)+interval 1 day)";
$sql = "select * from `gcm_users` where (`created_at` between {$first_day} and {$last_day})"
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("could not fire the query");
```